# For what are those functions used too?

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

Im learning more about solidity contracts and checking their source codes. In the current contract I was wondering about the following functions:

```
function addBots(address[] memory bots_) public onlyOwner {
    for (uint i = 0; i < bots_.length; i++) {
        bots[bots_[i]] = true;
    }
}

function delBots(address[] memory notbot) public onlyOwner {
  for (uint i = 0; i < notbot.length; i++) {
      bots[notbot[i]] = false;
  }
}
```

and about the **transfer()**

```
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        uint256 taxAmount=0;
        if (from != owner() && to != owner()) {
            require(!bots[from] && !bots[to]);
            taxAmount = amount.mul((_buyCount>_reduceBuyTaxAt)?_finalBuyTax:_initialBuyTax).div(100);

            if (transferDelayEnabled) {
                  if (to != address(uniswapV2Router) && to != address(uniswapV2Pair)) {
                      require(
                          _holderLastTransferTimestamp[tx.origin] <
                              block.number,
                          "_transfer:: Transfer Delay enabled.  Only one purchase per block allowed."
                      );
                      _holderLastTransferTimestamp[tx.origin] = block.number;
                  }
              }

            if (from == uniswapV2Pair && to != address(uniswapV2Router) && ! _isExcludedFromFee[to] ) {
                require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Exceeds the _maxTxAmount.");
                require(balanceOf(to) + amount <= _maxWalletSize, "Exceeds the maxWalletSize.");
                _buyCount++;
            }

            if(to == uniswapV2Pair && from!= address(this) ){
                taxAmount = amount.mul((_buyCount>_reduceSellTaxAt)?_finalSellTax:_initialSellTax).div(100);
            }

            uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
            if (!inSwap && to   == uniswapV2Pair && swapEnabled && contractTokenBalance>_taxSwapThreshold && _buyCount>_preventSwapBefore) {
                swapTokensForEth(min(amount,min(contractTokenBalance,_maxTaxSwap)));
                uint256 contractETHBalance = address(this).balance;
                if(contractETHBalance > 0) {
                    sendETHToFee(address(this).balance);
                }
            }
        }

        if(taxAmount>0){
          _balances[address(this)]=_balances[address(this)].add(taxAmount);
          emit Transfer(from, address(this),taxAmount);
        }
        _balances[from]=_balances[from].sub(amount);
        _balances[to]=_balances[to].add(amount.sub(taxAmount));
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount.sub(taxAmount));
    }
```

Why would you need those bot add and delete functions and in the transfer why would you need to do a transfer delay?

```
..
   require(
                              _holderLastTransferTimestamp[tx.origin] <
                                  block.number,
                              "_transfer:: Transfer Delay enabled.  Only one purchase per block allowed."
                          );
..
```